# How can i access query in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, routes

I have two components in **Next.js**. (Let's say `<Navbar />` and `<SearchResult />`.)

The `<Navbar />` has a search-bar where user can search for items and a **Search** button which, when clicked will redirect the user to the `<SearchResult />` page where the results are displayed. The `<Navbar />` component allows me to send the searched query but i cant catch it in the `<SearchResult />` component.

//I can see the query in the url-bar(`localhost:3000/searchresult?query=somequery`) but when i try to log this in console, it shows **undefined**.

Here's a code snippet to my `<Navbar />`:

```
'use client'
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useState } from "react";

const NavBar = () => {

    const router = useRouter()


    const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')

    const handleSearch = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault()
      
        setSearchQuery(searchQuery)

        //redirect the user to searchresults page
        router.push(`/searchresults?query=${searchQuery}`)
      }

      return (<Navbar className="bg-transparent">
          <NavbarItem className="bg-white rounded-md" >
            <input 
              type="text" 
              className="outline-none text-black p-2 text-small rounded-l-md"
              placeholder="Search for a Character"
              value={searchQuery}
              onChange={(e)=> setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}/>
            <button 
              className="text-black px-2 hover:text-emerald-400 transition-colors"
              type="submit"
              onClick={handleSearch}>Search</button>
          </NavbarItem>
        </NavbarContent>
      </Navbar>)
}

export default NavBar
```

And this is the code to my `<SearchResult />` component:

```
'use client'

import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"

const page = ({params} : {params: any}) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  const { searchQuery } = useParams()

  console.log(searchQuery)

    return (
      <div>
         Hello..
      </div>
    )
  }

export default page
```

I have looked everywhere but can't seem to find the fix for it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for useSearchParams.

```
'use client'
 
import { useSearchParams } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function SearchBar() {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams()
 
  const query = searchParams.get('query')
 
  // URL -> `/dashboard?query=my-project`
  // `query` -> 'my-project'
  return <>The query: {query}</>
}
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params